# How to make a preloader for webpage in dart

Tags: html, css, dart, dart-webui

I have a site that I build using the HTML, CSS3 and Dart. Now, how would I make a preloader, that would run before all the content for the page was loaded?

I was even thinking of using something like this: http://cssload.net/
so I am open for any suggestions...

Update: 
Something like this but in Dart:
http://gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader2/
http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/

Comment: Why do everyone write the name Dart in capital letters?

Answer (score 0):

Add an html code like this in your html page after the body tag..
choose any image you like..

```
<div id="preloader">
   <img id="spinner" src="http://cssload.net/preloaders/circular.gif" alt="" />
</div>
```

use this jquery code...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
/* the preloader division is visible until the whole page loades and then fades out using this code */
$(window).load(function() {
   $('#preloader').fadeOut(300, function() {
      $(this).remove();
   });
}); 
</script>
```

and then add this css code

```
#preloader,#spinner {  
     position:fixed;  
     top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; margin:auto; 
     background:#fff;  
     z-index:9999;  
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

it will work...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is jquery and not dart. I will post my solution later

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure svg solution and also customizable

```css
body {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  background-color: #333333;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #e8e8e8;
}
a{
   color: #e8e8e8;
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 310;
  stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  animation: dash 2s linear  infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  }
 
  25% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 15;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  }
}

.loader {
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from{ transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to{ transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div style=" display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;">
<svg class='loader'
   width="120"
   height="120">
   <circle
    class="progress-ring__circle"
    stroke="#D9DDE4"
    stroke-width="10"
    stroke-linecap="round"
    fill="transparent"
    r="52"
    cx="60"
    cy="60"/>
  <circle
    class="path" 
    stroke="#1a73e8"
    stroke-width="10"
    stroke-linecap="round"
    fill="transparent"
    r="52"
    cx="60"
    cy="60"/>
 
</svg>
  
  <a href="https://codesandbox.io/s/ring-preloader-ui-opeso" target="_blank">[Customize your own ring preloader]</a>
  </div>
```